# How to your game detect that you had a Collisions

Tags: javascript, game-development, phaser-framework

What I mean by how to your game detect that you had collisions is I want to make a function that checks if the Collisions state of two objects is true if it is true it will call a function if it is false it will not so in my case if the two boxes have a Collision it should call on a function to make the play button appear.

```
const gameState = {}

function preload() {
  // load our 'incredib/*  */le' sound here!
  this.load.image('intro1','/images/Screenshot 2023-10-20 10.20.39 AM.png');
  this.load.image('intro2','/images/Screenshot 2023-10-20 10.23.58 AM.png');
    this.load.audio('madcityintro', '/audio/a357cdfe-4a46-452f-a536-c41f8d57f35c.mp3')

}

function create() {
  // add our 'incredible' sound to our scene here!
  gameState.madcitysound = this.sound.add('madcityintro')
    gameState.madcitysound.play()
    gameState.intro1 =  this.physics.add.image(-100, 200, 'intro1')  
    gameState.intro1.setVelocityX(500);
    gameState.intro2 = this.physics.add.image(1230, 200, 'intro2') 
    gameState.intro2.setVelocityX(-500);
   gameState.block = this.physics.add.collider(gameState.intro1, gameState.intro2);
}
function update(){
}


const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 999,
    height: 500,
    backgroundColor: "0xFF3300",
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 0 },
            enableBody: true,
          }
    },
    scene: {
      preload,
      create,
      update
    }
  };
  
  const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

It just did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to build the check yourself, the `collider` function has this features builtin. [Checkout the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Factory.html#collider__anchor)

Simply add the function into the `collider` function as the third parameter.

**here a short demo:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {            
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: {
        preload,
        create
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function preload(){
this.load.image('image1', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/sprites/copy-that-floppy.png');
}

function create () {

   let counter = 0;
   let label = this.add.text(10,10, 'No Collision')
      .setOrigin(0)

   let img1 = this.physics.add.image(10, 90, 'image1').setScale(.5);
   let img2 = this.physics.add.image(400, 90, 'image1').setScale(.5);
   
   // set velocity to move images
   img1.setVelocityX(50);
   img2.setVelocityX(-50);
   
   // add collider for collision detection
   this.physics.add.collider(img1, img2, function(obj1, obj2){
        label.setText('We collided');
   });
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {            
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: {
        preload,
        create
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function preload(){
this.load.image('image1', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/sprites/copy-that-floppy.png');
}

function create () {

   let counter = 0;
   let label = this.add.text(10,10, 'No Collision')
      .setOrigin(0)

   let img1 = this.physics.add.image(10, 90, 'image1').setScale(.5);
   let img2 = this.physics.add.image(400, 90, 'image1').setScale(.5);
   
   // set velocity to move images
   img1.setVelocityX(50);
   img2.setVelocityX(-50);
   
   // add collider for collision detection
   this.physics.add.collider(img1, img2, function(obj1, obj2){
        label.setText('We collided');
   });
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```